# Есть ли разница между этими двумя кусками кода?

Tags: c

```
typedef enum {
  DISABLE = 0, 
  ENABLE = !DISABLE
} FunctionalState;
```

Есть ли какое-либо преимущество у такой записи или можно заменить более простым кодом?

```
typedef enum {
  DISABLE, 
  ENABLE
} FunctionalState;
```

Comment: а почему бы значение для ENABLE явно не присвоить 1? Приимущество первого способа в том, что мы явно задаем значения. Мало чего в будущем случится с компилятором:)

Comment: Если хотите максимальной переносимости, определяйте через `#define ENABLE 1; #define DISABLE 0`

Comment: @0andriy: Что такое `#define ENABLE 1; #define DISABLE 0`? Вот так вот с `;`? И как `#define` может улучшить переносимость?

Comment: @Ant, я думаю немного подумавши можно разобрать строчку. В комментарии невозможно вставить перевод строки. Насчёт переносимости, если вдруг захочется использовать один и тот же заголовок в разных программах, скажем, в качестве библиотеки, то  C и C++ по-разному будут трактовать это дело, так, вы не сможете сказать `e_var = 1;` в C++. Ну и редкий случай это `sizeof(ENABLE) == sizeof(int)` может быть *false* (но не обязательно). В остальном у *enum* преимущества по сравнению с.

Comment: @0andriy: Перевод строки - нельзя. Но `;` там более чем неуместно. А при чем вопросы переносимости на С++ в вопросе c тэгом [C] - мне не ясно вообще.

Comment: Как хотите, читающий да увидит, думающий да поймёт ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о получаемых в результате таких объявлений значениях enum-констант, то нет, разницы никакой нет. А уж есть ли тут какой-то "преимущество" говорить трудно, учитывая, то объявления немедленно эквивалентны.

Вариант `ENABLE = !DISABLE` явно выражает тот либо факт, что должно выполняться `ENABLE == 1`, либо тот факт, что должно выполняться `ENABLE != 0`. Какой из них - не ясно, но по крайней мере какая-то взаимосвязь между `DISABLE` и `ENABLE` явно передана.

Во втором варианте читателю кода никакой явной взаимосвязи не видно. То есть ничего не мешает читателю предположить, что данные константы могут иметь произвольные значения.